# Use dotnet.exe to build project in visual studio - skip msbuild redirection

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

**Is it possible to use dotnet.exe directly from visual studio "Build" command** (skip the use of msbuild.exe) ?

**Answer : Not Possible To Override the default command - see detailed answer below**

[image]

Current Version of Visual Studio 2022 17.2.11

Current Version  MSBuild  17.2.1.25201

The Purpose is to run Compile Net7 on older Visual Studio

Using the integrated console with msbuild.exe it fails.

[image]

Using dotnet.exe build succeed
[image]

Comment: Technically possible by creating a Makefile project (C++ workload required).  Practically not, you'll be harshly reminded about all the other components in VS that depend on knowing the target.  Which is why you have to upgrade to 17.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** possible to configure Visual Studio to change the 'Build' menu to use `dotnet` instead of `MSBuild`.

Visual Studio 17.2 doesn't support .NET 7. I assume there is a reason for not updating to Visual Studio 17.4 and that .NET 7 has been installed separately from Visual Studio.

You can add an 'External Tool' entry for `dotnet` and/or you can add a customized terminal profile. The standard 'Developer PowerShell' and 'Developer Command Prompt' profiles set the environment to use Visual Studio's install of tools and libraries. e.g. You could create a 'Command Prompt' profile from the 'Developer Command Prompt' profile by removing the Arguments: `/k ""%VSAPPIDDIR%\..\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`.

The `dotnet` tool embeds `MSBuild`. In a sense `dotnet build` is a 'redirect' to the embedded `MSBuild`. The second screenshot shows that the version of `MSBuild` embedded in the `dotnet` tool that is being run, is v17.4.0.

`dotnet` knows about and can build .Net Core/.NET 5+ projects, but doesn't know about .NET Framework and can't build .NET Framework projects. .NET Framework is Windows only and `dotnet` is cross-platform.

`MSBuild` on Windows can build both .NET Framework and .NET Core/.NET 5+ projects. But `MSBuild` needs to know how to locate the various SDKs and libraries. The screenshot shows that you are running MSBuild v17.2.1 and the error message indicates that you need at least MSBuild v17.3 for .NET 7; i.e. You could build with `MSBuild`, but you would need to use a newer version.

Comment: In addition, please be aware that the MSBuild that VS is using is a different application from the MSBuild that the dotnet CLI is using.
VS on Windows uses an MSBuild that was built targeting the full .NET Framework.
dotnet CLI uses an MSBuild that was built targeting .NET Core/5/6.
They also behave differently, e. g. very notably so during package restore.

Comment: It is actually the same build engine from the same source but configured differently and provided with different 'targeting' support. Legacy projects and SDK projects import different sets of files and some differences in behavior are differences between project types, not differences in the build engine.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Configuration must be quite different then. E. g. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6434#issuecomment-1325955062.
Also, the runtime environment for Roslyn SDK stuff like analyzers is different between CLI build and VS build, e. g. the versions of assemblies that are loaded by default are different.

Comment: "dotnet knows about and can build .Net Core/.NET 5+ projects, but doesn't know about .NET Framework and can't build .NET Framework projects" is not accurate. `dotnet build` can compile SDK style projects that target `netxxx` platforms, via ".NET Framework Targeting Pack Nuget Packages" https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/main/releases/reference-assemblies

Comment: I didn't know about the ".NET Framework Targeting Pack NuGet Packages". Thanks for sharing that. If I edited my answer to say that "out of box" and/or without adding optional packages (or something to that effect) dotnet can't build .NET Framework -- would that be accurate?

Comment: Unfortunately, latest .NET SDK does bring streamlined experience of ".NET Framework Targeting Pack NuGet Packages" so that you don't even need to explicit add this package reference (the SDK does that for you automatically). While the goal is probably not to let `dotnet` CLI work 100% for .NET Framework projects, clearly it supports many special cases now. You might check my answer, as I took another angle to explain the possible cause.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Visual Studio 2017, MSBuild becomes a core component of Visual Studio and ships with Visual Studio installer.

> MSBuild history can be found [here](https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-msbuild-cc72a217fa98).

Or say it in another way, that Visual Studio hooks to a specific version of MSBuild to perform all build operations, and will not support any other version (`dotnet` CLI is still MSBuild based). This is a fair design that eliminates all kinds of incompatibilities among different VS components.

Thus, you cannot force an old VS release to use newer `dotnet` CLI for .NET 7, and have to upgrade your VS to a certain version (VS2022 17.4) to match the desired MSBuild version.

As comparison, JetBrain Rider chooses a different approach and allow you to choose different engines (between MSBuild and .NET CLI, as well as different versions). They might share more pros and cons if they like, but I guess at least they have to test a lot more cases to avoid incompatibilities.